# How would you create a function to find the largest number in a Dynamic array?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

`This is what I have so far and I am new to using a dynamic array instrad of a regular one. Any help would be much appriciated.

```
public static int max(DynamicArray arr) {
        //TODO Find and return the largest number in the array
        int base = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i == arr.size(); i++){
            // compare values
            if (base < arr.indexOf(i)){
                // replace the base number with the highest number
                base += arr.indexOf(i);
            }
        }
        // return highest number
        return base; 
    }

private int size = 0; // the size the user thinks it is

public int size(){ 
        return size;
    }

public int indexOf(E element){ //TODO((3))
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if(data[i].equals(element)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

And this is the main ouput code.

```
//Code to call Find the High Number Assignment
        DynamicArray<Integer> highNumberArray = new DynamicArray<Integer>();
        Random randGen = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            highNumberArray.add(randGen.nextInt(100));
        }
        System.out.println("*********");
        System.out.println("The largest number in the array is: " + max(highNumberArray));
        System.out.println("");
```

---

Comment: What is a `DynamicArray`? Since it isn't a class that is part of the standard java api you might want to add the code for that class to your question.

Comment: What's wrong with the method you have right now? (Except `indexOf` is a misleading name.)

Comment: Sorry, the DynamicArray is: public class DynamicArray <E>.

Comment: k314159 - It just is not giving an output that makes sense. *********
The largest number in the array is: 0

Comment: @AnyaDinger  That doesn't help much unless you include the class or a link to its documentation.  But it sounds like it could be similar to an ArrayList.

Comment: My guess is that `base += arr.indexOf(i);` is the problem.  Shouldn't you just be assigning the value and not adding to base?  And I would set `base` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE;`  But it would also help if you edit your question to explain your thought process.  That might help you understand what is going wrong.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dVdYv9OBk_cq5_Vo9_t0-TT4ALemlPQJqi_9O572iyM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AnyaDinger I modified my comment.  In essence you want to set base to a minimum.  e.g Integer.MIN_VALUE.  Then if each subsequent value is greater than base, set base to that value.

Comment: @WJS I tried just assigning to the base but it also had the same result: largest number = 0.

Comment: @AnyaDinger  I think you want `get` instead of `indexOf`  Do you want to return the largest number or its location.  It isn't clear.

Comment: I want to get the largest number. Also I get an error when changing indexOf to get: Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.lang.Object'

Comment: You have a type problem in the last analysis. `E` has no connection to 'largest.' `E extends Comparable` would, or `E extends Number`. You might also use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,int))

Comment: @g00se The thing is this is for an assignment for school. That part of the code was given and can't be changed.

Comment: I see. You could stream it out: `public E max() {Object o = IntStream.range(0, size).mapToObj(i ->(Comparable)data[i]).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElseThrow();return (E)o;}`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems. Here are the basic ones.

- `for (int i = 0; i == arr.size(); i++){`  - this will iterate zero times unless `arr.size() == 0` and then it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are trying to get the `0th` item in an empty array. It should be `< arr.size()`
- `base += arr.indexOf(i)` - you said you wanted to get the number.  This gets the index for that number and adds it to base.  You want `base = arr.get(i)`

Now for the more complicated problem.  You can't use `<, ==, etc` when comparing objects.  You need to ensure your `max` routine only handles values that implement the `Comparable<E>` interface.  For example, we understand numbers and how they compare.  But what about Objects like picture frames?  Are they compared on the area, diagonal, frame thickness, or some combination of those?  Without knowing that we are helpless. So max ensures that the object under test has implemented that and we can use it. We don't have to understand it; just apply it and return the results.   Here is what it should look like.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> E max(DynamicArray<E> arr) {
     //TODO Find and return the largest number in the array
     E base = arr.get(0);
     for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++){
         // compare values
         if (base.compareTo(arr.get(i)) < 0){
             // replace the base number with the highest number
             base = arr.get(i);
         }
     }
     // return highest number
     return base; 
}
```

- It allows classes and subclasses of `E` to call this method to find the max of the array as long as they implement the `Comparable` interface.
- First it sets the `base` to item at index `0`.
- then it iterates starting at `1`.
- for `a.compareTo(b)`, Comparators return `-1, 0, 1` if `a is <, ==, or > than b`, respectively.  So you want to check that base < current value and if it is, assign the current value to base.
- When the loop is finished, return `base`

All of the above is based on my assumptions and I recognize it may be advanced.  I also suggest you discuss this with your instructor.
Also, as you stated you wanted to return the actual maximum value.  If you wanted to return the **location** (i.e. indexOf) that value, then an entirely different approach will be required.

Comment: @AnyaDinger  You're  most welcome.  I hope my explanations were adequate.  Your instructor can surely clarify (or possibly correct) anything I have said.